# Login warning from MySQL in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I am getting following error from the my sql server installed in localhost.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/asif/Sites/ver1/php_includes/db_conx.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/asif/Sites/ver1/php_includes/db_conx.php on line 2
>       php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not knownYYYYYYYYYYYYY

I am using following in the connect string:

```
<?php
$db_conx = mysqli_connect(“localhost”, “root”, "xxxxxx", "elearning");

// Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "YYYYYYYYYYYYY";
    exit();
}
mysqli_query($db_conx, "SET NAMES UTF8");
?>
```

For information I can login with the password and username through phpmyadmin. Suggesting a remedy would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you expected to provide the port number of your DB Server - like 'localhost:4306' ??

Comment: just off the top of my head, did you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and, if so, did that work? if it does, you may want to inspect your /etc/hosts file to see if localhost is listed there to point to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 4):

The quotes on `localhost` and `root` look weird, those are not normal quotes, if you use those I'm sure it won't work, also try setting variables before the con add use them to connect

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
//$db_conx = mysqli_connect("HostName", "UserName", "Password", "DatabaseName");
```